# Why are "from space" and "to space" not equal in jvm

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

- environment:jdk8u101
- os:centos6
- describe: "from space" and "to space" are not equal eden of heap. In my mind, "from space" and "to space" use copy algorithm, their space will always remain equal.
- can someone help me?
- I couldn't paste the screenshot, so I stuck the main data below

---

```
[root@05c46b9d1fc1 /]# jmap -heap 1
Attaching to process ID 1, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.101-b13

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 33 thread(s)
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 100
   MaxHeapSize              = 4294967296 (4096.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 357564416 (341.0MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 1431306240 (1365.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 716177408 (683.0MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 342360064 (326.5MB)
   used     = 251910632 (240.2406997680664MB)
   free     = 90449432 (86.2593002319336MB)
   73.58061248639093% used
From Space:
   capacity = 23068672 (22.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 23068672 (22.0MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 44564480 (42.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 44564480 (42.5MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 763363328 (728.0MB)
   used     = 26507512 (25.27953338623047MB)
   free     = 736855816 (702.7204666137695MB)
   3.47246337722946% used
```

Comment: Interestingly, both survivor spaces are also reported to be empty, which suggests, that this is not the normal state of the heap.

Comment: Yes, I haven't found it yet, but how can I locate the problem in a situation like this

Comment: That’s really hard to say without knowing anything about the history that led to this situation. Perhaps, no garbage collection has happened yet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the heap is growing (because your working set is growing), then the JVM is going to keep the ratio of new space size to old space size the same.  To do that, it needs to allocate a large "to" space than "from" space.

For a detailed understanding of how the JVM calculates the sizes of spaces, I suggest that you download and carefully study the source code for the *specific* version (release and patch) of OpenJDK that you want to understand.

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshot above again.Now I'm going to calculate a couple of things, and I want you to check them out for me.

Comment: I already did look at the screenshot.  It hasn't changed has it?

Comment: Sorry, that's not a complete description。Please look at the data above again."PS Old Generation" = 728M，because of "New Ratio" = 2，"PS New Generation" = 728/2= 364M。but now，"Eden Space" + "From Space" + "To Space" = 326.5+22+42.5 = 391M > 364M；if we use new "To Space" calculate: 326.5 + 42.5 * 2 = 411.5M > 364M。In a word，The new generation I'm counting is not half as old。thank you very much~

Comment: I cannot tell you *exactly* how or why the sizes of the spaces are what you observe.  I suggest that you download and *study* the OpenJDK source code to figure it out.  You are basically asking me to do your research for you, and I'm not prepared to do that.

Comment: Thank you again, I am afraid that I do not understand the source code, I will try to study it